# Object not found but working when created by "new"

Tags: symfony, type-hinting, symfony-3.3

It's working:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductPriceAccept;

public function editAction(Product $product)
{
   $ppa = new ProductPriceAccept();
   // further some operations on $product
}
```

But it doesn't want to work:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductPriceAccept;

public function editAction(Product $product, ProductPriceAccept $ppa)
{
   $ppa->setPrice();
   // further some operations on $product
}
```

I get:

```
AppBundle\Entity\ProductPriceAccept object not found.
```

Entity\ProductPriceAccept.php is:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/ProductPriceAccept.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Product_Price_Accept")
 */
class ProductPriceAccept
{
   // ...
}
```

I'm a little confused because usually type hint works well for me and as you can see up it works in similar situation for Product Entity. First solution works fine but I want to find out how the second makes problem. I cleared cache, checked typos. No idea what can do more.

Comment: Show your routing configuration. It looks like `ParamConverter` is not working.

Comment: Routing: 
admin_product_edit:
    path: /abcadm/product-edit/{id}/
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AdminProduct:edit }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a single parameter to be read, it can automatically read the repository.

With more than one, it needs some help.

> The id option specifies which placeholder from the route gets passed to the repository method used. If no repository method is specified, find() is used by default.
>
> This also allows you to have multiple converters in one action:

So, you will need an explicit @ParamConverter for ProductPriceAccept - you will also likely need `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;` line.

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}/comments/{comment_id}")
 * @ParamConverter("comment", class="SensioBlogBundle:Comment", 
 *     options={"id" = "comment_id"})
 */
public function showAction(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```

from: [@ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).

Comment: OK I see... So the easiest way seems to be $ppa = new ProductPriceAccept(); as I wrote in my first, working code. Less code. Or I miss something?

Comment: It very much depends what you are using those two entities for, and where you intend the contents to come from, and how.